# How can I use "should have done" at some point in the past?

Tags: tense, usage

For example,

> "I think I should have done my homework by yesterday."

I feel like this sentence will become:

> "I thought yesterday that I should have done my homework by the day before yesterday"

Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, your rephrasing of Present Tense ***I think** [something]* to Past Tense ***I thought** [it]* is perfectly correct. Except that for purely stylistic reasons, most native speakers wouldn't bother repeating ***yesterday*** (since it's contextually implied anyway). Note that *I think that **by next week I should have done it*** is also fine. ***To have done*** something refers to the state of having that action ***in one's past***, but the time when that state occurs could be in the Past, Present, or Future. And ***should** have done* doesn't really change that.

Comment: Thanks @FunbleFingers ! Your answer was simple and clear:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your rephrasing of Present Tense **I think** [*something*] to Past Tense **I thought** [*it*] is perfectly correct. Except that for purely stylistic reasons, most native speakers wouldn't bother repeating **yesterday** (since it's contextually implied anyway). Note that *I think that **by next week I should have done it*** is also fine. ***To have done*** something refers to the state of having that action ***in one's past***, but the time when that state occurs could be in the Past, Present, or Future. And ***should*** have done doesn't really change that.

--FF

Comment: Point taken. At the time I first wrote it (in the Past) *and* now (in the Present) *and* indefinitely far into the future, it will always be true that I ***should have posted*** this text as an answer rather than a comment! :)

Answer (score 1):

*By X* implies there was a deadline which implies responsibility.

*Have X {past-participle}* is a way to express that you accept(ed) responsibility for completing something.  So you probably want to say this:

> I think I should have had my homework done by yesterday.